# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'train'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I was trying to run the following coding in Juypter Notebook but received the following error:

```
Cell In[17], line 6
      4 import os.path
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 6 import train
      7 import time
      8 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'train'
```

Please advise how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you installed the module `train` on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Install [train](https://pypi.org/project/train/) package; so just put

```
!pip install train
```

on the first cell.

Comment: The 'train' package is not really a full package.

Comment: How can i  uninstall the 'train' package? Can the 'train' package be revised and re-install?